# Which should I close first, the PreparedStatement or the Connection?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, prepared-statement

When using a `PreparedStatement` in JDBC, should I close the `PreparedStatement` first or the `Connection` first? I just saw a code sample in which the `Connection` is closed first, but it seems to me more logical to close the `PreparedStatement` first.

Is there a standard, accepted way to do this? Does it matter? Does closing the `Connection` also cause the `PreparedStatement` to be closed, since the `PreparedStatement` is directly related to the `Connection` object?

Comment: Although according to the spec the statement should be closed when the connection is closed, JDBC drivers have been seen to have issues with this, so it is considered good practice to explicitly close the statement (and the result set).

Comment: Close things in the inverse order you opened them. All things.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The statement. I would expect you to close (in order)

1. the result set
2. the statement
3. the connection

(and check for nulls along the way!)

i.e. close in *reverse* order to the opening sequence.

If you use Spring [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) (or similar) then that will look after this for you. Alternatively you can use [Apache Commons DbUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) and `DbUtils.close()` or [`DbUtils.closeQuietly()`](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/DbUtils.html#closeQuietly(java.sql.Connection,%20java.sql.Statement,%20java.sql.ResultSet)).

Comment: Indeed. Some JDBC drivers will throw an exception on closing a result set or statement after the connection is closed.

Comment: That's correct. To the point: close the *resources* in **reversed order** as you acquired them.

Answer (score 7):

The following procedures should be done (in order)

- The `ResultSet`
- The `PreparedStatement`
- The `Connection`.

Also, it's advisable to close all JDBC related objects in the `finally` close to guarantee closure.

```
//Do the following when dealing with JDBC. This is how I've implemented my JDBC transactions through DAO....

Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
  conn = ....
  ps = conn.prepareStatement(...);

  //Populate PreparedStatement
  rs = ps.executeQuery();

} catch (/*All relevant exceptions such as SQLException*/Exception e) {
  logger.error("Damn, stupid exception: " , e);
} finally {
if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
                rs = null;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());
            }
        }

        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
                ps = null;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());
            }
        }

        try {
            if (conn!= null && !conn.isClosed()){
                if (!conn.getAutoCommit()) {
                    conn.commit();
                    conn.setAutoCommit(true);
                }
                conn.close();
                conn= null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            logger.error(sqle.getMessage(), sqle.fillInStackTrace());
        }
}
```

You can see I've checked if my objects are null and for connection, check **first** if the connection is not autocommited. Many people fail to check it and realise that the transaction hasn't been committed to DB.

Comment: All of that finally boilerplate should be condensed into a utility method (for example `DBUtils.close(rs, ps, conn);`). Also the advice about autocommit depends on the situation. Sometimes when there is an exception you do not want to commit at all. Also, the effort of explicitly setting the reference to null is almost always unneeded, because it will get dereferenced when the method exits, which is hopefully very soon after this, otherwise the method is likely too long.

Comment: @Yishai, yes, I forgot to mention that if there are exceptions and autocommit is off, you can do a rollback...Thanks for showing this.